# How to make amount of likes stay on page when reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find out how to make the amount of likes stay on the page when it's reloaded. Any pieces of code to help me make that happen?

```
var count = 0;
function clickFunc() {
  count += 1;
  var click = document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = count;
  var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
  if(count >= 1) 
    btn.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Are you fetching any data from a server/database? If not, you can set a cookie that you can then check for either an integer or boolean value. You can then disable the button dependent on that value.

Comment: Hi @Deskie - welcome to Stack Overflow. When adding code to questions there are a couple ways of formatting code, worth checking out. I just added 3 backquotes before and after the code snippet (` ` `) - but without spaces.

To answer your question, try Google searching browser storage options. These include the browser database, cookies, and possibly one other options...

Comment: I'm not very familiar with cookies..

Comment: alternatives for cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage

Answer (score 0):

You could write a solution using `localStorage`. Here is an example below. Ensure that the `checkStorage()` method is called on document ready so that the count is added to the DOM if it isn't there already.

```
//Run on Document Ready
function checkStorage() {
  if(!localStorage.getItem("count")){
    localStorage.setItem("count",0);
  } else {
    let stored = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count"));
    console.log('Storage Exists');
    var click = document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = stored;
    var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
    if(stored >= 1) { 
      btn.disabled = true;
    }
  }
}

//Run Button Click
function clickFunc() {
  let stored = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count"));
  stored++
  localStorage.setItem("count",stored);
  var click = document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = stored;
  var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
  if(stored >= 1) { 
    btn.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of storing likes locally? Is typically an aggregate for all users not just one user

Comment: You couldn't do that without being able to store the data remotely. My question above asked if they were storing the data server-side. I believe this to be a local project which is the basis of my response.

Comment: So the answer should be that remote storage would be required and there are numerous remote storage services

Comment: Why? That doesn't appear to be in their requirements. If this is something strictly run on one machine and one browser, it is achievable using some form of browser storage. Their intent isn't clear but I imagine they're learning web-dev and aren't so worried about the more complicated aspects.

Comment: @James Hi thank you for this code, I tried it and changed checkStorage() to getDocumentReady() and I still got nothing, and, I'm not able to click the button anymore, I think theres something wrong with the way I'm formatting my code, do you mind if you can use your code in mine for an example? Thanks